# How can I use Relay GraphQL client to upload the files

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, graphql-relay

I have the following use case:

I have an Apollo compatible file (form-multipart) GraphQL resolver for handling files (in the backend).
The React App is using the [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) client.

### How can I make an upload mutation using the Relay client?

The app is already using the latest Relay (v4.0).

I would like to avoid:

- setting up Apollo client in the app (just to make the file upload)
- fall back to REST and separate one request into two (graphql mutation + REST file upload).

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? I am having a similar problem

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Comment: I have a pretty good idea which direction I"m going to go, it's not in my current work sprint but will be in a few weeks / up to a month. For now, some links that are helping me out in the right direction:
[upload scalar](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/issues/9#issuecomment-433795841), [example with manual schema setting](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#examples). i think you'd use [this](https://madeintandem.com/blog/uploading-files-relay-modern/) but put the files right in the inputs instead. maybe. too complicated to try on ours without 5+ hours of work